# How to migrate data from an Informix database to MySQL

Tags: mysql, informix, data-migration

We have to migrate data from an Informix database to a MySQL database.

Help me how we can achieve it?

What steps or commands I have to use it? If you have any document or reference link that would be very much helpful.

Comment: There is a lot of tools which can be found in Internet by `informix to mysql migration tool`  searching string.

Comment: The primary tool for exporting an Informix database is `dbexport`; it produces a specific format, usually with pipe symbols `|` separating fields.  It includes the schema information.  An alternative is to manually create external tables (`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE …`) with `USING(FORMAT 'DB2', DELIMITER ',', DATAFILES(…))` to create CSV formatted data.  This is fiddlier.  The `dbschema` program can create the schema.
See IBM's Informix documentation for [CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=statements-create-external-table-statement). _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ There are some problems with the documentation which I'm going to be reporting as errata — notably, no mention of `FORMAT 'DB2'`.  See also [How do I convert key-value paired list into table with columns using `awk`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51104731/15168) and [How to convert `.txt` files to `.xls` files using Informix 4GL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19649368/15168), both of which feature a script for converting from Informix UNLOAD format to CSV format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step1: login to Informix and run the unload command. It will create a backup file named "file1" at current location under export directory.

```
UNLOAD to 'export/file1' SELECT * FROM db1.table1
```

Step2: Create table1 in MySQL Database.

Step3: Login to MySQL Database and set the global variable.

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL local_infile=1;
mysql> quit
```

Step4: Login to MySQL Database using below command

```
mysql --local-infile=1 -u root -p
```

Step5: Load the data into MySQL Databse using LOAD DATA command

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/export/file1'
INTO TABLE table1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```